# how to add row sum and col sum at the same time by subject and then arrange subject by total

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:
[image]

if I want to get the subtotal by subject as well as for each date, and also arrange subject based on total number of the subject, what should I do?

The final output should looks like following (blue part is the one we need  to add, and also total ELA (23) <total Math (47), so ELA will be in front of math):

[image]

The sample table can be build using codes:

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = c("Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "ELA", 
"ELA", "ELA"), date = c(1, 7, 14, 21, 1, 7, 21), A = c(1, 2, 
0, 9, 2, 6, 0), B = c(3, 5, 5, 1, 0, 5, 0), C = c(2, 1, 0, 8, 
0, 0, 0), D = c(0, 0, 2, 8, 0, 8, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr way :

```
library(dplyr)

c_order <- c('All dates', 1, 7, 14, 21)

df %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(across(A:D, sum)) %>%
  mutate(date = 'All dates', .after = 'Subject') %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% mutate(date = as.character(date))) %>%
  arrange(Subject, match(date, c_order)) %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(select(., A:D)))

# Subject  date          A     B     C     D Total
#  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ELA     All dates     8     5     0    10    23
#2 ELA     1             2     0     0     0     2
#3 ELA     7             6     5     0     8    19
#4 ELA     21            0     0     0     2     2
#5 Math    All dates    12    14    11    10    47
#6 Math    1             1     3     2     0     6
#7 Math    7             2     5     1     0     8
#8 Math    14            0     5     0     2     7
#9 Math    21            9     1     8     8    26
```

First for each `Subject` `sum` columns `A:D` and add a column '`date`' with value 'All Dates'. Bind this to original dataframe and arrange the data according to required order and perform a rowwise sum.

Answer (score 2):

Use package `Janitor` to do it fastly

```
df %>% mutate(date = as.character(date)) %>%
  group_split(Subject) %>%
  map_df(., janitor::adorn_totals, fill = "All Dates", name = "Sub-Total") %>%
  adorn_totals(where = "col")
         

   Subject      date  A  B  C  D Total
       ELA         1  2  0  0  0     2
       ELA         7  6  5  0  8    19
       ELA        21  0  0  0  2     2
 Sub-Total All Dates  8  5  0 10    23
      Math         1  1  3  2  0     6
      Math         7  2  5  1  0     8
      Math        14  0  5  0  2     7
      Math        21  9  1  8  8    26
 Sub-Total All Dates 12 14 11 10    47
```

If you won't change column `date` into a charachter one, it will be totalled also

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution. The main functions are

1. `by` and `addmargins`, to compute the totals per groups of `Subject` and the row totals;
2. a second loop (`lapply`) to put the column totals as the first row.

The rest of the code puts everything together.

```
res <- by(df[-1], df[1], FUN = function(x){
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  rownames(x) <- x[, 1]
  addmargins(x[, -1], margin = 1:2) 
})
res <- lapply(seq_along(res), function(i){
  x <- as.data.frame(res[[i]])
  row.names(x)[row.names(x) == "Sum"] <- "All dates"
  y <- cbind.data.frame(Subject = names(res)[i], date = row.names(x), x)
  names(y)[ncol(y)] <- "Total"
  y[order(y[["Total"]], decreasing = TRUE), ]
})
i <- sapply(res, '[', 1, "Total")
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, res[order(i, decreasing = TRUE)])
row.names(res) <- NULL

res
#  Subject      date  A  B  C  D Total
#1    Math All dates 12 14 11 10    47
#2    Math        21  9  1  8  8    26
#3    Math         7  2  5  1  0     8
#4    Math        14  0  5  0  2     7
#5    Math         1  1  3  2  0     6
#6     ELA All dates  8  5  0 10    23
#7     ELA         7  6  5  0  8    19
#8     ELA         1  2  0  0  0     2
#9     ELA        21  0  0  0  2     2
```

Comment: arrange part need some adjustment. within subject, it is ordered by date; the subject order is decided by total for All dates

Comment: @Stataq Done, see if it now solves the problem. The code was changed to use `addmargins`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Total = sum(c_across(A:D))) %>% 
   bind_rows(df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Total = sum(c_across(A:D))) %>% group_by(Subject) %>% summarise_at(vars(A:Total), sum)) %>% 
   mutate(date = replace_na(date, 'All Dates')) %>% arrange(Subject, desc(Total))
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  Subject date          A     B     C     D Total
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ELA     All Dates     8     5     0    10    23
2 ELA     7             6     5     0     8    19
3 ELA     1             2     0     0     0     2
4 ELA     21            0     0     0     2     2
5 Math    All Dates    12    14    11    10    47
6 Math    21            9     1     8     8    26
7 Math    7             2     5     1     0     8
8 Math    14            0     5     0     2     7
9 Math    1             1     3     2     0     6
```

Comment: arrange part need some adjustment. within subject, it is ordered by date; the subject order is decided by total for All dates.